# Decode Arabic characters cid mapping

Tags: python

I am trying to decode a string of Arabic characters using the following code
some characters are not replaced correctly and the spaces are not right at all

```
char_code_mapping = {
    "(cid:993)": "م",
    "(cid:987)": "ك",
    "(cid:931)": "ح",
    "(cid:991)": "ل",
    "(cid:909)": "ا",
    "(cid:937)": "د",
    "(cid:913)": "ب",
    "(cid:971)": "ع",
    "(cid:941)": "ر",
    "(cid:984)": "ق",
    "(cid:955)": "ص",
    "(cid:917)": "ت",
    "(cid:943)": "ز",
    "(cid:997)": "ن",
    "(cid:910)": "ـا",
    "(cid:1004)": "هـ",
    "(cid:1011)": "ـيـ",
    "(cid:927)": "جـ",
    "(cid:3)": " ",
}

line = "(cid:993)(cid:987)(cid:931)(cid:991)(cid:909)(cid:3)(cid:937)(cid:913)(cid:971)(cid:3)(cid:941)(cid:984)(cid:955)(cid:3)(cid:917)(cid:943)(cid:971)(cid:3)(cid:997)(cid:910)(cid:1004)(cid:1011)(cid:927)"
decoded_line = ""
i = 0
while i < len(line):
    if line[i:i+9] in char_code_mapping:
        decoded_line += char_code_mapping[line[i:i+9]]
        if line[i:i+9] == "(cid:3)":
            decoded_line += " "
        i += 9
    else:
        i += 1

reversed_decoded_line = decoded_line[::-1]
text_output_path = "decoded_output.txt"
with open(text_output_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as text_file:
    text_file.write(reversed_decoded_line)
print(f"Reversed decoded Arabic text saved to {text_output_path}")
```

The correct output should be `جيهان عزت صقر عبد الحكم`

Comment: `if line[i:i+9] in char_code_mapping` That assumes every key in your mapping is 9 characters long. But some are longer than that and some are shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead, apply the following short regex approach (with [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)):

```
import re

# ... your initial dict/line

pat = re.compile(r'\(cid:\d+\)')
decoded_line = pat.sub(lambda m: char_code_mapping.get(m.group(), ''), line)[::-1]
print(decoded_line)
```

---

```
ـجـيــهاـن عزت صقر عبد الحكم
```